# Is there any way to disable aero snap feature for particular WPF window?

Tags: wpf, aero-snap

I would like to use the window without enabling the default feature of aero snapping....i could do this by disabling the aero snap feature from the control panel....but i need to disable it for specific WPF Window alone.

Answer (score 0):

Sure... just make the `Window` un-resizable (if that is a real word):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Views.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: No I should not do that....because i need to resize my window....for some needs....